# Simplify numerical radical expressions with multiple terms

Tags: radicals

I'm trying to solve:

$$\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt7} \cdot \sqrt {21}$$

I assumed this would breakdown to:

$$\sqrt{\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{21}{1}}$$

The exercise says I should break it down to:

$$\sqrt 6\cdot\sqrt\frac{21}{7}$$

What they didn't do is offer any explanation as to why the whole number 21 suddenly becomes 3 and $\frac{6}{7}$ suddenly becomes the whole number 6.

If someone could explain how this works I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Note that $21/7=3$. It may help to start like you did and do the math. A full simplification will result in the nice $3\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole number $21$ is not suddenly becoming $3$, nor is $\frac{6}{7}$ becoming $6$.  What is actually happening is that we can re-order our terms to change the product $\frac{6}{7}\cdot 21$ into $6 \cdot \frac{21}{7}$.  The reason why we are able to do this is due to the fact that our numbers are associative under multiplication.  See?  $$\frac{6}{7} \cdot 21 = \frac{6\cdot 21}{7} = 6 \cdot \frac{21}{7} =6\cdot 3$$

Comment: I think i see now... is it just a different way of saying:  $\frac{6*21}{7}=\frac{126}{7}=18$

Comment: Instead of writing $\dfrac{6\cdot 21} 7 = \dfrac{21\cdot 6} 7 = \dfrac{21} 7\cdot 6 = 3\cdot 6$, the simpler way would be $\dfrac{6\cdot 21} 7 = 6\cdot\dfrac{21} 7= 6\cdot 3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the advice, I'll make the change.

Comment: @LrdSqrl2507  essentially, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's going to take a bit more practice, but this helps immensely.

Answer (score 1):

**Cancel before multiplying!**  Thus:
$$
\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt7} \cdot \sqrt {21} = \sqrt6 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{21}7}\text{ and } \underbrace{\frac{21} 7 = 3}_{\text{canceling the 7}}.
$$
Then you have
$$
\sqrt 6 \cdot \sqrt 3 = \sqrt 2\cdot\overbrace{\sqrt 3\cdot\sqrt 3}^{\text{This is 3.}} = 3\sqrt 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{6}{7}\times 21}=\sqrt{\dfrac{6}{7}\times 7\times 3}=\sqrt{6\times\dfrac{1}{7}\times 7 \times 3}
$$
and $\dfrac{1}{7}\times 7 =1$.